# NgIf a parameter is a certain value

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have an application in which you can add or edit values to a database.

When I'm editing values I want certain parameters to only show up when the value of `StatusCodes` has a certain value.

Html code:

```
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Status Code</label></td>
    <input type="text" #StatusCode (ngModel)="StatusCodes" value="{{StatusCodes}}">
</form>                                         

<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Eta</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Eta (ngModel)="Etas" value="{{Etas}}">
</form>
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Etd</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Etd (ngModel)="Etds" value="{{Etds}}">
</form>
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Ata</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Ata (ngModel)="Atas" value="{{Atas}}">
</form>
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Atd</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Atd (ngModel)="Atds" value="{{Atds}}">
</form>
```

For example I want the Eta form to appear when the value of StatusCode is xxx.

Something like this:

`<form class=form-group *ngIf="StatusCodes == 'xxx'">`

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: That is the correct syntax, though your `ngModel` has the wrong sytnax, it should be `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: It's the correct syntax. What is not working as expected?

Comment: yes, correct syntax

Comment: Uhh I swear it didn't work when I tried it before posting but it works now.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the example I posted was the correct answer.

```
<form class=form-group *ngIf="StatusCodes == 'xxx'">
```

Leaving up the question if it'll help anyone.

Comment: It says I need to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer.

Comment: It might be worth also investigating [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html)